# Simple multithreading without getch

Tags: c, multithreading

So far I've worked with processes and threads only on Linux platform.
Now I tried to move on Windows. And I got immediately stopped on very simple program.
Can you tell me why my program doesn't write anything if I remove the line with getch?
I want my thread to finish without me pressing anything. 
Thank you in advance

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc() 
{ 
    printf("lets print something"); 

    return 0; 
} 

VOID main( VOID ) 
{ 
    DWORD dwThreadId; 
    HANDLE hThread; 

    hThread = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                        // default security attributes 
        0,                           // use default stack size  
        ThreadFunc,                  // thread function 
        NULL,                // argument to thread function 
        0,                           // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);                // returns the thread identifier 

    // Check the return value for success. 

   if (hThread == NULL) 
   {
      printf( "CreateThread failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() ); 
   }
   else 
   {
      _getch();
      CloseHandle( hThread );
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are running the program in VS the probably the console windows will disappear immediately. By giving _getch(), the console window will wait till you hit _getche().

Comment: Yeah, my first thought. Then I tried it in terminal with gcc. Didn't work.

Comment: then probably your main thread is getting closed before creating the other thread. Hence you are not able to see the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your box is relatively idle, the OS is quilte likely to signal the thread creation request to another core, so allowing the 'main' thread, (the one created by the process loader), to run on quickly.  By the time your new thread gets round to calling the OS with the printf call, the main thread has already returned, the state of all threads for that process has been set to 'never run again' and a termination request queued up for it on its inter-processor core driver.  The new thread is exterminated there and then and the now-redundant termination request discarded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how should i fix this?
I tried adding usleep, same result.

edit: Then I tried Sleep, it works.

Comment: @user31 Simple, wait for the thread to terminate before existing. See `WaitForSingleObject`, although you shouldn't use `CreateThread` anyhow - see `_beginthreadex` and the CreateThread documentation for why.